# How to count number of tags/elements inside a tag and reduce font size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I count number of tags inside semantics or inside em tags, whichever is fine I think but I want to count all of them until the last one.
I want to get the number of tags inside semantics or em tags and then check if tags < 5 reduce font size to 8pt

```html
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(255, 86, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

<em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f1" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">

<semantics>

<annotation>jfrefeofjeroieofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>

</semantics>
</em>
</div>

<br>




<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(0, 200, 150); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

<em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f2" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">

<semantics>

<annotation>jfrefe<apply>ofjeroie</apply>ofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjer<apply>ofjerofjofoer</apply>jrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>

</semantics>
</em>
</div>
```

Can this be done via tags in jQuery/javascript, because I can't add classes or id to all the the different tags I have inside semantics tag?

First semantics tag has 5 tags inside annotation, apply, csymbol, annotation.

Second one has 6 : annotation, apply, apply, csymbol, apply, annotation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively query all children of a specific HTML element and increment a counter accordingly.

To do this we need to get a reference to the object in question - e.g. the `<semantics>` tag. JavaScript provides the **getElementsByTagName()** function which returns a HTMLCollection - more or less an array.

In your case it would consist of two objects since there are two `<semantics>` tags. If we're interested in the first one we now feed this object `document.getElementsByTagName("semantics")[0]` into the aforementioned function and query it's **.children** property - which again returns a HTMLCollection. If we do this as long as there are children left we can ultimately get the number of children in total.

Here's an example:

```js
let number = 0;

function count(ele) {
  var children = ele.children;
  for (var a = 0; a < children.length; a++) {
    number++;
    count(children[a], number)
  }
}

count(document.getElementsByTagName("semantics")[0]);
console.log("children: " + number);
number = 0;
count(document.getElementsByTagName("semantics")[1]);
console.log("children: " + number);
```

```html
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(255, 86, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f1" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
    <semantics> <annotation>jfrefeofjeroieofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>
    </semantics>
  </em>
</div>
<br>
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(0, 200, 150); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f2" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
    <semantics> <annotation>jfrefe<apply>ofjeroie</apply>ofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjer<apply>ofjerofjofoer</apply>jrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>
    </semantics>
  </em>
</div>
```

## Update

As stated above, `document.getElementsByTagName("semantics")` returns a HTMLCollection. Using a simple for-loop we can iterate over it's elements and execute a condition if the number of child elements is below 5.

Since you want to reduce the font size of the `<semantics>` parent `<em>` element, we can use the **.parentElement** property to get a reference to it and ultimately change it's font size using **.style.fontSize**.

Here's another example:

```js
function count(ele) {
  var children = ele.children;
  for (var a = 0; a < children.length; a++) {
    number++;
    count(children[a], number)
  }
}
var number;
var semantics = document.getElementsByTagName("semantics");
for (var a = 0; a < semantics.length; a++) {
  number = 0;
  count(semantics[a]);
  if (number < 5) {
    semantics[a].parentElement.style.fontSize = "8px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(255, 86, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f1" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
    <semantics> <annotation>jfrefeofjeroieofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjerofjerofjofoerjrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>
    </semantics>
  </em>
</div>
<br>
<div class="formula__content match js-match" data-color="#ff5600" data-algorithm-type="f" style="background-color: rgb(0, 200, 150); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <em class="match js-match" data-algorithm-type="f2" data-color="#f2a3ca" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
    <semantics> <annotation>jfrefe<apply>ofjeroie</apply>ofjerfje<apply>rofjerofjofoerjrf</apply>eorfefjfre<csymbol>feofjeroieo</csymbol>fjerfjer<apply>ofjerofjofoer</apply>jrfeorfefjfrefe<annotation>ofjeroieofje</annotation>rfjerofjerofjof</annotation>
    </semantics>
  </em>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. But there is the problem that I have more than two of these tags and I don't want to access them as you do individually. I want to check all of them and then reduce font size to only those that have i.e. children < 5

Comment: Sorry @ga1996 - I missed that part of your question. I've updated my answer!